# search for two strings, then add results together

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file that searches for two different strings in a file. Then take the first line from the first search and the first line from the second search and make them into one line.

I realized that this is way over my skill in batch so a little help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

---

```
@echo off
for /f %%G in (file.txt) do (
findstr "word1" *.* > result.txt
findstr "word2" *.* >> result.txt)
```

---

Example:

file.txt:

```
hello i'm a line with word1 
hello i'm a line with word2
hello i'm another line with word1
hello i'm another line with word2
hello i'm yet another line with word1
hello i'm yet another line with word2
```

result.txt:

```
hello i'm a line with word1hello i'm a line with word2 
hello i'm another line with word1hello i'm another line with word2
hello i'm yet another line with word1hello i'm yet another line with word2
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far. SO is not a "write code for me free" type of site.

Comment: so edited with my work at the moment

Comment: Are the two words fixed, or do they come from `file.txt`?

Comment: how do you mean? The words exist in file.txt but I chose which words to search for.

Comment: Are you restricted to batch? Doing this in PowerShell or even VBScript would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the number of line pairs to show in the variable `PairsToShow`:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "FileName=file.txt"
SET "Word1=word1"
SET "Word2=word2"
SET /a PairsToShow=3

SET /a Lines1=0, Lines2=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr "%Word1%" "%FileName%"') DO (
    SET "str=%%a"
    SET /a Lines1+=1
    SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
    SET "$1!Lines1!=!str!"
    FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('set "$1"') DO (IF "!"=="" endlocal)&SET "%%b=%%c"
)
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr "%Word2%" "%FileName%"') DO (
    SET "str=%%a"
    SET /a Lines2+=1
    SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
    SET "$2!Lines2!=!str!"
    FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('set "$2"') DO (IF "!"=="" endlocal)&SET "%%b=%%c"
)
SET /a Lines=Lines1+Lines2
ECHO(%Lines% lines read from %FileName%.
IF %Lines1% leq %Lines2% (SET /a MaxPairs=Lines1) ELSE SET /a MaxPairs=Lines2
IF %PairsToShow% gtr %MaxPairs% (
    ECHO only text for %MaxPairs% pairs NOT %PairsToShow% :/
    GOTO :END
)
(FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,%PairsToShow%) DO (
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    CALL SET "Line1=%%$1%%a%%"
    CALL SET "Line2=%%$2%%a%%"
    <NUL SET /p "=!Line1!"
    ECHO !Line2!
    ENDLOCAL
))> result.txt
ENDLOCAL
TYPE result.txt
:END
PAUSE
```

Comment: I get all the lines with "word1" and "word2" but I need the first line from the word1 search and the first line from the word2 search to be one line
example: file.txt: hello i'm a line with word1
         hello i'm a line with word2
         result.txt: hello i'm a line with word1hello i'm a line with word2

Comment: @user2553264 you can try my edit :)

Comment: thank you for your answer! But I only get this: 
file.txt:hello i'm a line with word1 
file.txt:hello i'm a line with word2 
in result.txt 
did it work for you?

Comment: Now you get "the first line with the found word". Not right?

Comment: yes! but the first line in result.txt should be "the first line with the found word1" + "the first line with the found word2"

Comment: Thank you! You are an angel! This only did the first pair of words is it possible to make it do more pairs (look at my edit of the post)

Comment: In the second line 2 x word2 ?

Comment: sorry my bad, word1 of course!

Comment: It can be done, but only if you don't have special characters in your text, eg. `=` and  `%`. Otherwise you can use GNUWin32 tools.

Comment: no that won't be a problem :)

Comment: Please do not forget accepting my answer. I make usually no question enhancements, **only** in intresting cases `:)`

Comment: you flatter me! but do this one work for more then one pair?

Comment: as much as you want and pairs available in the two text files. need some time...

Comment: if i would realize that i needed to use special characters in my text how would i proceed...? :)

Comment: as I said, in this case use [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) tools. And ready now!

Comment: Does it work? Nothing more then that the cmd opens and closes happens for me?

Comment: Sure! Result is in `result.txt`. Put a line with `pause` to the end of script.

Comment: there is no result.txt, and it still closes when i put the pause!

Comment: My guess is that i have done something wrong

Comment: or what do you mean with "Set the number of line pairs to show in the variable PairsToShow:"

Comment: The code reads the file `file.txt` line by line and store it in the memory. After that it displays line pairs: `line1+line2` and `line3 + line4` and so on. The variable `PairsToShow` tells the program, how many line pairs to show. Bus as I see suddenly: I have to make some more edits. Please be patient :)

Comment: How could I not be patient! :) Take as much time as you need! And some more after that

Comment: I's a really `huge` program now :) EnjoY!

Comment: I LOVE YOU! I'm serious if you asked me to marry you right now I would say yes!

Comment: @ Endoro Hello! :) I have a question if you have a minute :/